# Filtering XML nodes in memory without DOM?

Tags: xml, language-agnostic, xml-parsing, sax, smalltalk

Given a big XML I want to have PART of the XML structure in a tree in memory (THIS IS NOT DOM!!)
for example given

```
<MAIN>
    <A>
        <B>1</B>
        <C>2</C>
        <D>3</D>
            <H>7</H>
            <I>9</I>
        <E>2</D>
    </A>
    <A>
        <B>4</B>
        <C>5</C>
        <D>6</D>
            <H>3</H>
            <I>0</I>
        <E>3</D>
    </A>
</MAIN>
```

after the user selects nodes B and H, I want to have in memory

```
<MAIN>
    <A>
        <B>1</B>
        <C>2</C>
        <D>3</D>
            <H>7</H>
    </A>
    <A>
        <B>4</B>
        <C>5</C>
        <D>6</D>
            <H>3</H>
    </A>
</MAIN>
```

sometimes the user wants to filter by node contents, like all B nodes greater than 3, etc.

is there a (SAX?) library to do such thing?
preferably in Smalltalk but any other language will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is a SAX library included in VisualWorks.

Comment: Does that SAX library enables building a DOM-subtree and edit it?

Answer (score 0):

In java land, using either JDOM or DOM4J (and possibly also XOM), you can write a customized builder to achieve what you want.

An example for [DOM4J](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/faq.html#large-doc)

Answer (score 0):

An [STX](http://stx.sourceforge.net/documents/spec-stx-20070427.html) processor allows one to process a large document in streaming fashion, but to retain (possibly transformed) portions of that document in [variables](http://stx.sourceforge.net/documents/spec-stx-20070427.html#variables) or [buffers](http://stx.sourceforge.net/documents/spec-stx-20070427.html#buffers).